# Intellij IDEA With Multiple Gradle Projects

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am working on two Gradle projects. One of these projects is a supporting library that will be used by other projects in the future so project A depends on project B but not as a 'multi module project'. The dependency is to be resolved through the artifact repo so project a declares it as a compile dependency using it's maven coordinates.

My problem is when working on these two projects in IntelliJ changes to project B aren't made available to project A until I install it (using the Gradle Maven plugin) in my local repo. This is kind of annoying and slows down my workflow.  Is there a way to get IntelliJ to automatically update the dependency internally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is supported in the latest versions of Gradle and IntelliJ.  It is known as a [Composite Build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

Composite builds can be declared in the project's `settings.gradle` file as follows:

```
includeBuild '../my-app'
```

or by using the `--include-build` command line argument:

```
$ gradle --include-build ../my-utils run
```

Take a look at the [Composite Builds with Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA Webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klk2W02wJ0o) for instructions on how to configure the integration.

Answer (score 0):

In IDEA 2017 you can right-click on the gradle module and use `Composite Build Configuration` to link the current module to one or more gradle module already opened in the current workspace.